# Squashing aggregated rows with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Given a table `my_data` like this:

```
 id | name | surname | age
----+------+---------+------
 1  | john | smith   | NULL
 1  | NULL | smith   | 32
 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL
 1  | john | smith   | NULL
 1  | john | NULL    | 32

CREATE TABLE my_data(id,name,surname,age)
AS ( VALUES 
  (1::int, 'john', 'smith' ,NULL::int),
  (1, NULL,   'smith' ,32),
  (1, NULL,   NULL    ,NULL),
  (1, 'john', 'smith' ,NULL),
  (1, 'john', NULL    ,32)
);
```

For the same `id`, the values (if present) in the respective columns are always the sames so how can I "squash" them to get:

```
 id | name | surname | age
----+------+---------+------
 1  | john | smith   | 32
```

## My attempt

A `cross join lateral` for each column is my only idea so far, but I doubt is good:

```
select 
distinct column1, c2.value, c3.value, c4.value
from my_data md
cross join lateral (select column2 from my_data where column1 = md.column1 and column2 is not null limit 1) as c2(value)
cross join lateral (select column3 from my_data where column1 = md.column1 and column3 is not null limit 1) as c3(value)
cross join lateral (select column4 from my_data where column1 = md.column1 and column4 is not null limit 1) as c4(value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `percentile_disc`

I would think something like this would be the fastest,

```
SELECT id,
  percentile_disc(0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name NULLS LAST)    AS name,
  percentile_disc(0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY surname NULLS LAST) AS surname,
  percentile_disc(0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY age NULLS LAST)     AS age
FROM my_data
GROUP BY id;

 id | name | surname | age 
----+------+---------+-----
  1 | john | smith   |  32
(1 row)
```

Here we're using `percentile_disc` an [*Ordered-Set Aggregate*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#functions-orderedset-table) described as *"discrete percentile: **returns the first input value whose position in the ordering equals or exceeds the specified fraction**"*. So,

- if that position is "0", it's essentially `first_value` over the rows being aggregated.
- if NULLS are last (`NULLS LAST`), the first value *won't* be null, and that's all that matters here (because you said *"for the same id, the values (if present) in the respective columns are always the same"*)

You could also do this, I think, with `first_value` in a Window Function, and then pull from that with `DISTINCT ON`.

## Using `mode`

If you want the consensus of the non-values, we can do that too. I was assuming `percentile_disc` was what the OP wanted. Another option is to use `mode()` which is a different *Ordered-Set Aggregate Function*. It's described as, "returns the most frequent input value (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent results)". It looks like,

```
SELECT id,
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)    AS name,
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY surname) AS surname,
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY age)     AS age
FROM my_data
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: great! I didn't know percentile_disc (at least wasn't clear from the doc). I already tried first_value/window_function but I couldn't make it work :(

Comment: @EvanCarroll As mentioned in my "solution", I had never heard of `percentile_disc` - could you explain why it still gives a "correct" answer, even if "rubbish" data is added?

Comment: @Vérace updated.

Comment: So, are you saying that if the "first" value to emerge is "incorrect", then your method will fail - or at least provide the incorrect answer - I'm basically saying that the "correct" answer is the "consensus" - i.e. the value with the most common occurrence!

Comment: @Vérace that's not what I took from "respective columns are always the sames"

Comment: @Vérace even if so though, you can do that with `mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sort_expression)` =)

Comment: @Vérace updated again.

Comment: @Vérace doh! I just realized you weren't asking the question

Comment: @EvanCarroll `mode()` is even better (I asked the question:)) - as I found a few cases where actually some terms are slightly different (like 4 times "smith" and 1 "smitth")

Comment: @Randomize - you could also UPPER the name fields! Have updated my answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - complete rewrite of answer - no PostgreSQL special functions required!

Comment: @EvanCarroll Probably I missed something, but... Isn't the `percentile_disc(0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY <field> NULLS LAST)` is totally equal to `min(<field>)`? (`select id, min(name), min(surname), min(age) from my_data group by id;` produces desired result using much simpler syntax...)

Answer (score 1):

The interesting solution by Evan Carroll got a +1 (never even heard of `percentile_disc`!).

However, I have another possible solution, which has the advantage of being generic (for those `RDBMS`s which have `CTE`s - i.e. the `WITH` clause).

It does **NOT** require any special PostgreSQL specific functionality - other than the `LIMIT` - which has corresponding keywords in other severs.

(Complete rewrite!)

I did the following:

Created my table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  person_id INTEGER,
  person_firstname VARCHAR (25),
  person_surname VARCHAR (25),
  person_age INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES
( 1, 'john', 'smith', NULL),
( 1,   NULL, 'smith',   32),
( 1,   NULL,    NULL, NULL),
( 1, 'john', 'smith', NULL),
( 1, 'john',    NULL,   32),
( 1, 'John', 'Smith', 3456);  <-- note capitalised names and outlier age!
```

And then ran the following:

```
WITH fname AS
(
  SELECT person_id, person_firstname
  FROM person
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
),
lname AS
(
  SELECT person_id, person_surname
  FROM person
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  ORDER BY COUNT(person_surname) DESC
  LIMIT 1
),
age AS
(
  SELECT person_id, person_age
  FROM person
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  ORDER BY COUNT(person_age) DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT fname.person_firstname, lname.person_surname, age.person_age
FROM fname
JOIN lname on fname.person_id = lname.person_id
JOIN age   on lname.person_id = age.person_id;
```

with the (desired) result (correct for the data):

```
 person_firstname | person_surname | 
------------------+----------------+-----
 john             | smith          |  32   <--- average good - outlier ignored!
(1 row)
```

This solution provides the correct solution even with outliers - (see previous edits of this post for the problem!) - it does depend on the majority of answers being correct. Using the `UPPER()` function would also eliminate any capitalisation issues.

Of course, a far better solution would be to do the data scrubbing **before** it gets anywhere near the HDD - putting in `NOT NULL` declarations for example would be a good start!